# Pip Python установка библиотеки из файла.py

Tags: python, pip

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите плз, можно ли установить пакет непосредственно из python-файла, как это делается из консоли (pip install ...), только из файл.py

Comment: нет, я просто хочу попробовать с помощью py скрипта попробовать установить на удаленном сервере нужные мне библиотеки, чтобы понять где ошибки в тесте который я не могу пройти, и отправить себе на емайл код ошибок), есть вероятность, что не пустить установить без прав рута, но а вдруг получится, но для этого их надо сначала установить

Comment: А, то есть вы хотите запустить команду pip install изнутри скрипта? Ну тогда вы можете попробовать сделать это через os.system или subprocess, только вот удалённый сервер скорее всего просто не даст вам это сделать

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Nicholas, решение работает? Вам ещё нужен ответ на вопрос?

Comment: @mironovmeow у нас тут база знаний, поэтому ответ на вопрос можно написать всегда (если вопрос соответствует правилам)

Comment: @mironovmeow, помогло с os.system. Спасибо всем)

Answer (score 1):

Изучал этот вопрос пару лет назад: нет, програмно не получится. У pip нет стабильного программного апи для запуска установки из репо. Всё завязанно на аргументы запуска команды.

Используйте subprocess или os.system для запуска pip.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно.

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

install("requests")

import requests

print(requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip').text)
```

Comment: Прошу заметить, что это работает для pip до версии 10.0.0. После они отказались от `pip.main`. Подробнее можно узнать в [документации](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program).